# What is the difference between the normal INVITE and the INVITE on hold in a session using SIP protocol?

Tags: sip

hi all am new to software field and stack overflow too. I am analyzed the back end flow of a session between the caller and the callee using SIP protocol. I am little bit confusing on the normal INVITE and INVITE on hold. can anyone explain the difference between them?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check following link:

https://andrewjprokop.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/understanding-sip-re-invite/

The most common use for re-INVITE is call hold. The party putting the call on hold sends a re-INVITE with SDP indicating that media will no longer be sent. That same party will take the call off hold by sending another re-INVITE with SDP indicating that media transmission will resume.

Comment: Thanks @os11k. I have one more doubt why we are mentioning NULL IP in SDP? Can you explain the technical reason behind that?

Comment: First of all: The null IP address approach should be avoided. From book "IP Telephony: Deploying VoIP Protocols and IMS Infrastructure": RFC 2543 described a basic form of floor control by sending new INVITE messages with the ‘c’ SDP parameter set by convention to null ‘0.0.0.0’ to mute an endpoint, and re-invite it later (non null ‘c’ parameter) when allowed to take part in the conference. Since RFC 3261 and its more formal description of media offers and answers, it is now prohibited to use this convention.

Answer (score 4):

A normal SIP INVITE will mostly have CSeq 1. But the Re-INVITEs will have greater CSeq value. A difference between the INVITE and Re-INVITE is that their CSeq will be incremented else UAS will reject the message. An existing dialog can be modified in the form of Hold/Retrieve/Codec level changes using a Re-INVITE.
Please keep in mind that a Re-INVITE is different from a Re-Transmitted INVITE

Answer (score 3):

I'm too late to answer! But adding one more difference.

One difference between invite and re-invite is obviously the re-invite has **incremental cseq** number than the initial invite.

The other difference is re-invite will have the **totag** value where in the initial invite doesn't.

This is an example of an initial invite because there is no `totag` on the To: header

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Difference between Re-Invite & Re transmission of Invite  is identified by C-Seq Number.
i.e Re transmission of Invite contain the same C-seq No that was previously used by the corresponding Invite.But in Re-Invite which is used to change the session parameter the c-seq is Increment by 1.

Re-Invite is commonly use for Call hold , that is set the a(attribute-Line) in SDP as send only or it can change the c(Connection Address) to 0.0.0.0.